# need help with equasion

Tags: divisibility

Well. My computer has fritzed up and

I'm having to perform some lenghy task, it's processing 20 files every 2 seconds, it's at 459000 of 854528

Roughly how long in seconds might it take?

I've currently tried;

854528 - 45900 / 20 = 831578

Is this,correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Note that it is processing $10$ files every second. (Do you see why?) How many files does it have left to process? How many seconds will it take to process that many files?

**Addendum**: One reason your answer was nowhere close to correct is that you forgot to include the parentheses in $$(854528-45900)/20.$$ Order-of-operations is a harsh mistress. See if you can figure out the other reason.

Comment: 79105.6 is the first one? (854528 -459000) /10 * 2?

Comment: I'm not sure where the first number came from, and I'm not sure what the second "question" is. Double-check both your calculations *and your original post* for accuracy, and use complete sentences, if possible.